# Control type-level "evaluation" in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm writing an open source TypeScript library that'll be published on NPM. I'm looking for some "hacks" that might make my library more helpful to its users.

For instance, some library functions will include some non-trivial type operations. One example is

```js
export type UndefinedOptional<A> =
  { [P in keyof A]?: A[P] } &
  { [L in { [K in keyof A]: undefined extends A[K] ? never : K }[keyof A]]: A[L] }
```

which intends to make potentially undefined keys in an object optional.

My problem is that this leads to inferred type signatures like

```js
const myThing: Thing<UndefinedOptional<...>> = ...
```

where the `UndefinedOptional` operation "leaks" into "user space". Understanding what this is is something I'd prefer to not burden library users with needlessly.

What I would like instead is to "force" the evaluation of this type-level function (similarly to how you'd force a thunk in lazy evaluation.) into the type that `UndefinedOptional` would return.

I'm also interested in forcing typescript to evaluate types like `{ foo: number } & { bar: string }` into `{ foo: number, bar: string }` if there are any hacks that may help with that.

It's fine if the methods for achieving this is a bit "hacky", by which I mean for example relying on behaviour that isn't explicitly standardised, may change between versions, etc.

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=65#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqA7AJsAZgSw2CwHkwZ8IMBDAGwB4BBAPjgF4AoOOAbzgG0ACnEJwA1sEQRccRgF0A-AC5ZQuXAC+cAGRduvAQBkRGA-wDSJ8ZOmy5KgK7Y8hYnFAxg2AM6rz6hTgiADdgKDgVSw1+CSkZeXtVQ3UNDg4kFDgAFQALQgBzJlY2WTTcJwBjCio4CBQoamqMJncQTx9eDWYACmoVRgBKFUwcAiJSckoaBhZePW4oYBgHKFMMB1paOGpfagxEDlSOCqpveBAVXIL6Pgu4M6gCgBo4RBV1gFsAIzC4AB84E5Rq4sJpikENlsdtt9mkAPRwuAAdQgG1BtAgoTguGgCByqEIuDCi1BGVQJzRcB+93wHzAtHwBDcMAgHAR2wGcAAQsAzpc8hhCrcVA9nq9AkpPj9wql2V9OTyYJ4oPzrrdlPcYI9Bf9Ac4xm4XogJRDvr8AUCXONNDoDHdRTqusdTvBEOxavVGlNuiABvDESjKRisTjwjB8SYiVASQhkOTUbRQdTvLT6Yz8MzWezhZrtfkjRqpb9UmS4ABNd0jK3EMhNOg3OD2rVit6m6W6y0G0FdIA) a playground with some simplified examples of my definitions

Answer (score 0):

Using a mapped type, we can "compress" the type into an object literal:

```
type Expand<T> =
    // if T is an array
    T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        ? number extends T["length"] // if T is not a tuple
            ? Expand<T[number]>[] // expand the element type and wrap it back into an array
            : { [K in keyof T]: Expand<T[K]> } // T is a tuple
        : T extends object // if it's not primitive
            ? { [K in keyof T]: Expand<T[K]> } // expand it recursively
            : T; // T is a primitive so leave as is
```

This does not give you a lot of control over the resulting type. For example if you have an interface named `MyInterface`, the resulting type won't show `MyInterface` but the actual type `MyInterface` holds.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHmAhgOwCYB4AqA+KBeAKCmKkygjmAjQGcoAlCRVAe2QBsQBBAJx8RDoArsgDWyFgHdk2IiXkB+KMiEBbAEYQe5StVR1MAbQBE7agHNgAC2MBdOfMdQl8JGiyGVGrbeyH7Tk4AXFAA3lCGANJQAJbIUKIQICwAZqS2Ia4oGEaRvlAAvg6OIWQUVLRQLOoAVhAAxsDFgc5hEdFxCUmp6ZkI2R55uEUt8qUA3AQEoJCkAIz4sP3uxjTAPHHmxtiTAPS7JAB6CtPg0JgATItZ7gAsFzsE+0cnM+cAzNfLGOtCEI-PYjHU6zTC3L5uDDhFIsFghNYbZDmQpQABkbXUiB4IS8mm0BQBByBrzOpAArBCBtDYfD1psUejwpjsco1HiGRjEAAvBQhAAU4QAjkI4CF1LCzCgOUKRaKoOKWJL4gUAJT+QqEl4g84ANkp7gFUBhcKgCPpBTRnJZuK0hTVvj2RKgwLepAA7PqMIZqSazUjpfKsTi2baCgAaNrG2mI5EWxmB60h-EOp5O4FAA) is a playground with some tests.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using these two types. The first one works similarly to the other solution as it recursively resolves any type aliases into actual types.

The other is an attempt at not making that so deep and "destroying" even those aliases I do care about.

```
/** Normalize type by recursively applying any type aliases and merging explicit intersections. */
type Normalize<T> =
  T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (...args: Normalize<A>) => Normalize<R>
  : { [K in keyof T]: Normalize<T[K]> }

/** Merges intersection `{a} & {b}` into `{a, b}`. *(Similar to `Normalize` but only one level deep.)* */
type ShallowNormalize<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
```

Note that the solution is from this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71426138/985454

---

There are another two solutions in this TypeScript repo issue
[Suggestion: Provide a way to force simplification/normalization of conditional and mapped types #47980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47980)

```
type Expand<T> = T extends unknown 
  ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
  : never;
```

And recursive variant

```
type Expand<T> = T extends unknown
  ? { [K in keyof T]: Expand<T[K]> }
  : never;
```