# VSCode type preview is not simplifying type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've got a fairly complicated type derived from another. In the type declaration and in type annotations the type is correctly derived:

[image: Correctly derived type on declaration]

However, when hovering actual JS variables of the specified type, the type is not simplified and instead the popup shows the chain of all the applied type modifiers:

[image]

Is there any way to force VSCode to always show the simplified type?

TS Version: 4.6.2
VSC Version: 1.65.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there's no way to alter the types that VS Code shows on hover, but you can define an identity type to get rid of all the type applications.

Here's a recursive one that also properly handles functions:

```
// Normalize type by recursively applying any type aliases and merging explicit intersections.
type Normalize<T> =
  T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (...args: Normalize<A>) => Normalize<R>
  : {[K in keyof T]: Normalize<T[K]>}
```

For example:

```
type A = { a: string }
type B = { b: number }
type NotNormalized = A & B // inferred type: A & B
type Normalized = Normalize<NotNormalized> // inferred type: { a: string, b: number }
```

The type `Normalize<User>` should show you the normalized `User` type on hover. Other versions of `Normalize` (often called `Expand`) are possible, depending whether you want to normalize only the top level or recursively, and whether you need to deal with function properties.

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL5rvW)

Comment: This answer led me to the solution for my specific problem, but it should be noted that your mileage may vary: in my case, I resolved declaring a `type _DirtyUser = Lots<Of<Types<And<Generics…>>>` and then just redeclaring a mapped type which does nothing: `type User = { [KeyType in keyof _DirtyUser]: _DirtyUser[KeyType] }`. Surely is one more step, but the popup is much more legible now and I've also noticed TS has an easier time inferring it in the code in some edge cases.

Comment: Why is there `[T] extends [any]`? I have just tried `T extends any` and it seemingly worked. _(Although I may have not used sufficiently complex type to begin with.)_

Comment: It seems that it can be further simplified to just the true branch since `T extends any` is never false.

Comment: Yep, you're right. The condition was there to prevent union distribution, but that's not necessary as the mapped type distributes over unions anyway. The reason for `[any]` instead of `any` was to emphasize the brackets were there to block distribution, but for `any` or `unknown` they can be left out.